# Add new column in existing database table

Tags: magento-1.9, database

I have created file mysql4-upgrade-1.6.0.1-1.6.0.2 in which code is like,

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->getConnection()
->addColumn($installer->getTable('newsletter_subscriber'),'subscriber_name', array(
    'type'      => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT,
    'length'    => 255,
    'after'     => 'subscriber_email', // column name to insert new column after
    'comment'   => 'Subscriber Name'
    ));   
$installer->endSetup();
?>
```

Also changed in config file. It is like,

```
<modules>
        <Mage_Newsletter>
            <version>1.6.0.2</version>
        </Mage_Newsletter>
</modules>
```

But still column is not added in the database 'newsletter_subscriber' table. Any help?

Comment: Don't edit Magento core files directly; Have a look there, it tells you how to create setup files for custom modules: http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-install-install-upgrade-data-and-data-upgrade-scripts/

Comment: Is there any way if I want to upgrade core file and core module for this? @Mayers

Comment: you need to create a custom module, and in the setup file of this custom module you can modify core tables. The only reason for this, is that a Magento upgrade would wipe your changes (The link  above gives you a detailed tutorial about how to create this module)

Comment: Thank you dear! I tried your words and it works. @Mayers

Comment: great news! I have added my comment as a response, if it's helped you, please mark it as accepted so  we can close off this post

Answer (score 1):

If above syntax is not working for you then you can try below syntax to

```
<?php
$installer = $this;


$installer->startSetup();

try {
        $tableName = $installer->getTable('newsletter_subscriber');
        $installer->run(" ALTER TABLE {$tableName} ADD `subscriber_email` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL  ; ");
        $installer->endSetup();


} catch (Exception $e) {
        // to do
}
```

and also check your `core_resource` table if entry is already there for your new version then revert and try again

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->getConnection()
->addColumn($installer->getTable('newsletter/subscriber'),
'subscriber_name', 
array(
    'type'      => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT,
    'length'    => 255,
    'after'     => 'subscriber_email', // column name to insert new column after
    'comment'   => 'Subscriber Name'
    ));   
$installer->endSetup();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't edit Magento core files directly; Have a look there, it tells you how to create setup files for custom modules: http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-install-install-upgrade-data-and-data-upgrade-scripts/

You need to create a custom module, and in the setup file of this custom module you can modify core tables. The only reason for this, is that a Magento upgrade would wipe your changes (The link above gives you a detailed tutorial about how to create this module)